# When to use Money data or Decimal Data type in sql server to store costing values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, sqldatatypes, currency

What is preferable data type to store the costing value ? Money or Decimal
whats the programmatic diff bet them?
asp.net Data Annotation for asp.net Model for Money data type ?

Answer (score 13):

`Decimal` type provides more precision to hold intermediate results to get the results you expect.

Disadvantages of `money` datatype:

1. It is proprietary, so porting it is a pain.  It is one of the many "Sybase Code Museum" features from decades ago.  Remember the early versions of UNIX?
2. Writing code in dialect when you don't need to make you sound like a hillbilly to people that speak the language. You are better off with DECIMAL(s,p) so you can use a properly sized column.
3. It does display and formatting in the back end, with commas and dollar signs.  That defeats the purpose of a tiered architecture.
4. The MONEY data type has rounding errors.

Ref:msdn

Comment: It only has "rounding errors" if used wrong, i.e. if someone multiplies or divides `money` by `money`, which is of course nonsensical. If `money` is multiplied/divided by an appropriate type that causes the expression to be promoted to arbitrary precision, then there's no issue at all.

Answer (score 4):

You should prefer `decimal` as `money` datatype is not precise.

You may also check [Performance / Storage Comparisons : MONEY vs. DECIMAL](https://sqlblog.org/2008/04/27/performance-storage-comparisons-money-vs-decimal) by Aaron Bertrand

Comment: "not precise"? Please. It has 4 entire decimal places of precision. Calling that not precise is totally arbitrary, based on no point of reference, and, erm, imprecise. For those who do not need to store more than 4 digits after the decimal point, `money` is _exactly_ as precise as they need.